# How to identify `selected` values in ChoiceType in Symfony forms

Tags: forms, symfony

I am trying to create a page where the user can create a batch of new invoice records in the database. Each Member has both "Default Amount" and "Default currency" properties assigned in the entity. For the default currency, this is stored in the database as either `E` (Euros) or `D` (Dollars).

However, in the page to create the new invoices, the "Default amount" is populated correctly for each member, however the select box for currency only ever shows "Euro" even if the member has *Defaultinvoicecurrency*=`D`. This is because `selected` is never being added to any of the select options of what is stored in the database for the Members.

[image]

If the form is submitted with a currency selected from the dropdown then these are correctly added to the database (`E` or `D`).

**Member Entity:**

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\COLUMN(type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/",
 *     match=true,
 *     message="Please check - amount should have up to two decimal places")
 */
protected $defaultinvoiceamount;

/** eg E=EUR or D=USD
 * @var string
 * @ORM\COLUMN(type="string", length=1)
 */
protected $defaultinvoicecurrency;
```

**Invoice entity:**

```
class Invoice
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="InvoiceBatch", inversedBy="invoice_ids")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="invoicebatch_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $invoicebatch_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Member", inversedBy="invoice_ids",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="member_id",     referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $member_id;

    /*
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\COLUMN(type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/",
     *     match=true,
     *     message="Please check - amount should have up to two decimal places")
     */
    protected $amount;

    /**  eg PEN or USD
     * @var string
     * @ORM\COLUMN(type="string", length=1)
     */
    protected $currency;
```

**Controller:**

```
public function newInvoiceAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $members = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Member')->findActiveMembers();

    $batch = new InvoiceBatch();
    foreach($members as $member) {
        $invoice=new Invoice();
        $invoice->setMemberId($member);
        $invoice->setAmount(   $member->getDefaultinvoiceamount()   );
        $invoice->setCurrency( $member->getDefaultinvoicecurrency() );
        $invoice->setinvoicebatchid($batch);
        $batch->addInvoiceId($invoice);
    }

    $form=$this->createForm(InvoiceType::class, $invoice);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && ($form->isValid())) {
    /* ... */
}
```

**FormType:**

```
class InvoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('amount', MoneyType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Amount',
            ))

            ->add('currency',ChoiceType::class, array(
                'data'=> 'Defaultinvoicecurrency',
                'choices' => array('Euro' => 'E', 'US Dollar' => 'D'),
                'choices_as_values' => true,
            ))
    /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the 'data' => 'Defaultinvoicecurrency' setting in your form class? I'm not really sure what is the goal of that definition in your code, but as you seem to be passing Invoice entity instance for the form you probably should be using just the 'currency' field...

Comment: @ejuhjav....thank you very much! I had been trying just about everything except for excluding `data=>` altogether(!). Feel free to post an answer that data isn't required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are passing the Invoice entity instance to your form, the correct entity data field is 'currency'. I.e. you need to remove the superfluous 'data' definition from that form field:

```
->add('currency',ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array('Euro' => 'E', 'US Dollar' => 'D'),
    'choices_as_values' => true,
))
```